# numpy fromfile using remote paramiko SFTPFile connection

Tags: python, numpy, paramiko

I have a binary data file on a server that I want to read with numpy.
Rather than logging into the server and running my Python code there, I note that I can make a remote SFTP connection to the file using the `paramiko` SSH2 module:

```
import paramiko

# get SSH connection to remote server (els039)
ssh_client=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.load_system_host_keys()
ssh_client.connect("els039")

# now get SFTP client connection:
sftp_client = ssh_client.open_sftp()

# get connection to remote file
rfile = sftp_client.open('2013041506.dat')
```

Now, I can use the standard Python file reading functions to access the data, but I cannot use Numpy to read the data. For instance, I want to read 3 arrays from the data like this (of known lengths):

```
zdat = np.fromfile(rfile, dtype=">f8", count=zdat_len)
udat = np.fromfile(rfile, dtype=">f8", count=udat_len)
vdat = np.fromfile(rfile, dtype=">f8", count=vdat_len)
```

But numpy does not like the fact that `rfile` is of type `paramiko.SFTPFile`.

Is there a way to do what I want - or should I just SCP the whole file over to a local directory?

Answer (score -1):

### If you prefer to get what you want

then you ought to reverse-engineer the `numpy.fromfile()` methods of accessing the `<fileObject>` to read structure / data-cells and create on your own an ad-hoc addOn, subClassed for the `paramiko.SFTPFile` objects / instance-methods.

### If you prefer to get a working result fast

then you may rather opt to download (instantiate) a plain `.dat`-file instance on your `<localhost>` filesystem, that the `numpy.fromfile()` and/or `numpy.loadtxt()` standard methods can process & have the job done this way.